# Непонятное поведение альтернативы в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Добрый день. Необходимо написать регулярное выражение для поиска строковых литералов и комментариев. В приложенном (по ссылке) регулярном выражении - именованные группы соответственно выполняют свои функции.

**Вопрос**: если убрать правую (от альтернативы между группами) часть регулярного выражения, то в строке `//"dhfghfgh"` найдется подстрока `"dhfghfgh"`. Целиком же это регулярное выражение найдет весь комментарий `//"dhfghfgh"`, хотя опять же поиск строки выполняется вначале (ведь стоит слева от альтернативы). С чем связано такое поведение? Не должен ли движок, найдя соответствие для левой части альтернативы, прекратить проверку?

Регулярное выражение в тестере: https://regex101.com/r/1EEHvx/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> С чем связано такое поведение?

С тем что перебор текста идет посимвольно. И для вашего регулярного выражения

```
(?<StringLiterals>(@"([^"]|"(?=")|(?<=")")*")|"([^"\r\n]|(?<=\\)")*")|(?<Comments>(\/\/.*|\/[*](.*?|\s)*[*]\/))
```

если текущий символ не удовлетворяет первой части

```
(?<StringLiterals>(@"([^"]|"(?=")|(?<=")")*")|"([^"\r\n]|(?<=\\)")*")
```

проверятся удовлетворяет ли он второй части

```
(?<Comments>(\/\/.*|\/[*](.*?|\s)*[*]\/))
```

А так как слеш у вас стоит раньше текста, то после нахождения первого слеша регулярное выражение начинает отрабатывать свою вторую часть (то есть проверятся следующий символ на слеш и дальше идет захват всех символов до конца строки).

> хотя опять же поиск строки выполняется вначале (ведь стоит слева от альтернативы)

Это не так. Написано выше.

> Не должен ли движок, найдя соответствие для левой части альтернативы, прекратить проверку?

Нет. Так как строка полностью удовлетворяет второй части регуляного выражения.

P.S. Загляните в отладчик [своей регулярки](https://regex101.com/r/1EEHvx/1/debugger).

Comment: Спасибо большое/